# onClick change img to new img and back to original

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onclick, ionic-framework

This is function that is triggered by click on image with ng-click="promjeni1()", it changes that sk1 img with one of zkockice[].src that are also images, is it possible that within same function on second click to change back to original img, it will be used like select/deselect, and can i assign some value to changed img aka selected like 'true', for later use so i can do something like if selected img do .....

```
$scope.promjeni1 = function () {
    if(sk1 === kockice[0].src) {
      sk1.src = document.getElementById("sk1").src = zkockice[0].src;
      } else if(sk1 === kockice[1].src) {
      sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = zkockice[1].src;
      } else if(sk1 === kockice[2].src) {
      sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = zkockice[2].src;
      } else if(sk1 === kockice[3].src) {
      sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = zkockice[3].src;
      } else if(sk1 === kockice[4].src) {
      sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = zkockice[4].src;
      } else if(sk1 === kockice[5].src) {
      sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = zkockice[5].src;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am sure it is possible.... Hold state of last image. If it is set, than put old image back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, this code looks so confuse, I think its better if you make a method like this:

```
function getImgSrc(str){
  for (var i = 0; i < kockice.length; i++) {
    if(kockice[i] == str) return kockice[i].src;
  }
}
```

and you use like this:

```
sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = getImgSrc(sk1)
```

Now with the new conde the answer of your question:

You need to storage the old src to return to it.

Like this:

```
function getImgSrc(str){
  for (var i = 0; i < kockice.length; i++) {
    if(kockice[i] == str) return kockice[i].src;
  }
}
var oldSrc = null;
$scope.promjeni1 = function () {
  if(oldSrc){
    sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = oldSrc;
    oldSrc = null;
  }else{
    oldSrc = sk1 = document.getElementById("sk1").src = getImgSrc(sk1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can do something to this effect 
(please correct me if I'm way off)

```
//this is just an idea

function(){
if(getElementByTag("click"){
do something
click.attribute = "notclick";
}

if(getElementByTag("notclicked"){
do something
click.attribute = "click";
}
}


// tag in your html code
<img id="clicked" src="" title="image">
```